# How might I use QSettings to load different setups

Tags: qt, qsettings

I have a Qt application that requires the ability to load from several settings files to behave in a distinct way. For example lets say my app can support several variations, VAR1, VAR2, VAR3, ...  One of my menu entries allows me to load settings. Currently, I do this using a QSettings object and it works fine. But now I want to implement a different variation. Instead of manually setting 20 or more settings, I would like to load from a preconfigured settings file.

QSettings does not allow me to change source, as far as I can tell. I looked at the static method QSettings::setPath but that can only be done once prior to instantiating the QSettings object.

My hope is to create ways to:
  1 - Load factory defaults
  2 - Save a user settings file with a user specified name
  3 - Recall a user settings file by name.

I would prefer not to have to rewrite QSettings to meet my needs if at all possible.

Answer (score 4):

One of the `QSettings` constructors takes a file name:

```
QSettings::QSettings (const QString& fileName,
                      Format format, 
                      QObject *parent = 0);
```

Just use that to make as many `QSettings` instances as you need:

```
QSettings s1("path1.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
QSettings s2("path2.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
```

If you needed to copy between them you could look through `QSettings::allKeys()` and get the values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to access QSettings like an INI file ? It allows you to set up the location of the INI file

```
 QSettings settings("/home/petra/misc/myapp.ini",
                    QSettings::IniFormat);
```

Comment: The problem is once you load the settings, there is no easy way to subsequently load a different settings file.

Comment: Why not? Just like in the Dave Mateer's answer.